# Autocomplete performance issue

Tags: c#, linq

I am using textbox autocomplete features with large data.

Instead of hitting SQL Server every time, I keep all data in an application variable and then with the help of Linq and C#, I am fetching the data, but performance is not good - sometimes retrial was late and after tabbing data list getting frizzed so please some one help me the same, also is there any alternate technique for this?

My code is as follows:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Application["MasterData"] == null)
{
    string sDBName;
    UserMaster objUserMaster = new UserMaster();
    sDBName = Session["DBName"].ToString();
    dsData = objClient.GetClientConfiguration(sDBName, UtilityClass.sDeploymentDBName, Convert.ToString(Session["ConnString"]));

    if (CheckNullData(dsData))
        HttpContext.Current.Application["MasterData"] = dsData;
}
else
{
    dsData = (DataSet)HttpContext.Current.Application["MasterData"];
}

strFilter = "DignosisCode like '" + SearchText.ToUpper() + "%'";

dvFilterData = new DataView(dscodedata.Tables[1]);
dvFilterData.RowFilter = strFilter;
dtFilterData = dvFilterData.ToTable();

dtFilterData = dtFilterData.DefaultView.ToTable();

DataList = (from DataRow row in dtFilterData.Rows
            select row.Field<string>("DignosisCode") + " " + row.Field<string>("Description")).ToList();
```

Comment: Just to be sure, could you use breakpoints to check if the long time is not due to `HttpContext.Current.Application["MasterData"]` always being null and getting re-set?

Comment: according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.application(v=vs.110).aspx, the Application object is read-only. You should use ApplicationInstance, which is settable, instead I think: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.application(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Instead of refreshing your list from 0 to n. Check your list if no data then load your full data. If your list hasrows then load only the last data changed from sql.